# get value from DOM and add it to a button value

Tags: javascript

I have a bit complex problem, 95% solved, but stack in a final step as do not know js :( Wrote my whole code in PHP but smarty framework not let me run it (for security reason of course) - The problem is getting the EAN code on my site (search in a separated database) and echo the results in a modal popup window.

Everything is working fine except I do not know how to search and finally add that value to a button to start the process...

Here is the js in the head

```
function showthestock(str) {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("showithere").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "searchresult.php?q=" + str, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

and the HTML button etc..

```
<button id="myBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" value="1234567890123" onclick="showthestock(this.value)">stock in our shop...</button>
```

.....
modal popup etc...
....

The code I need EAN from the page is for example:

```
<div class="product-reference">
  <label class="label">EAN </label>
  <span itemprop="sku">065541068780</span>
</div>
```

And the code works well with a manually added EAN code in the button, but I do not know how to  Stole' the EAN from the site and add it to the button's value automatically...

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

Is there just a single EAN per page??
If so, give your span an ID.

`<span itemprop="sku" id="ean">065541068780</span>`

Then do

```
var ean = document.getElementById("ean").innerHTML;

document.getElementById("myBtn").value = ean;
```

If you cannot modify the HTML, you can try isolating the EAN with regex:

```
var regex = new RegExp(/<span itemprop="sku">([^<]*)<\/span>/gi);
var matches = regex.exec(document.body.innerHTML);

var myEAN = matches[1];
```

Comment: Helli Mik! Unfortunately the "1234567890123" value is not an ID or not a CLASS itself, so I can not now how to call it with getelementby.. :( I can not modify the structure of a product-reference code

Comment: If you cannot modify the HTML at all, try isolating your EAN with regex. I added it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
var parent = document.querySelector('div.product-reference');
var child = parent.querySelector('span[itemprop="sku"]').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('myBtn').value = child;
});
```

Find `product-reference` and here get `span` with EAN number. Next set this value to button.
Hope this help

Comment: Hello! It would be great (I can now stole the EAN code from the shop, but I can not implement it to a button already have an onclick function :( please see button code above

Answer (score 0):

Thanks For Mike and Mosquito for the great ideas, finally it works like a charm...